# Tensorflow LSTM Model predicting the same constant value

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I want to predict usage every hours using historical data(2021.01~2021.08) and weather data.

I want predict next 24 hours usage with data from the past 3 days(72 hours)

train data is 2021.01.31~2021.07.31 and test data is 2021.08.01~2021.08.31.

I did data scaling(RobustScaler) and one-hot encoding.

Here is my code:

```
final_x_train.shape : (49393, 72, 276)
final_y_train.shape : (49393, 24)
final_x_test.shape : (7220, 72, 276)
final_y_test.shape : (7220, 24)

val_data = (final_x_test, final_y_test)

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=1024, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=final_x_train.shape[-2:]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer= adam)
model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 72, 1024)          5328896   
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 72, 1024)          0         
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 1024)              8392704   
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 24)                24600     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 13,746,200
Trainable params: 13,746,200
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________


early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, verbose=1)
path_checkpoint = 'short_normal_best_model.h5'
callback_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path_checkpoint,monitor='val_loss',
                                      verbose=1,save_weights_only=True,save_best_only=True)
model.fit(final_x_train, final_y_train, validation_data=val_data, batch_size=256,
          epochs=1000, verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stopping, callback_checkpoint])

y_pred = model.predict(final_x_test)
y_true = scaler_usage.inverse_transform(final_y_test)
y_pred = scaler_usage.inverse_transform(y_pred)

y_pred
array([[6.094296 , 6.0942955, 6.094296 , ..., 6.094296 , 6.094296 ,
        6.094296 ],
       [6.094296 , 6.0942955, 6.094296 , ..., 6.094296 , 6.094296 ,
        6.094296 ],
       [6.094296 , 6.0942955, 6.094296 , ..., 6.094296 , 6.094296 ,
        6.094296 ],
       ...,
       [6.094296 , 6.0942955, 6.094296 , ..., 6.094296 , 6.094296 ,
        6.094296 ],
       [6.094296 , 6.0942955, 6.094296 , ..., 6.094296 , 6.094296 ,
        6.094296 ],
       [6.094296 , 6.0942955, 6.094296 , ..., 6.094296 , 6.094296 ,
        6.094296 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Why my model predicting the same constant values?

Comment: scaler_usage is RobustScaler().

Answer (score 0):

If you try to predict on each hour separately the usage (not for one hour), you have to use `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='softmax'))` and `categorical_crossentropy` or `mse` (`categorical_crossentropy` works better in practice).

Otherwise, you are trying to predict a real/float number and using the `mse` loss function for this purpose, then you must `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))` on your last layer in order for the model to be able to learn.

So the `relu` activation on your last layer is not suitable for neither case described above.